# Karate: Schema validation in multi level nested array

Tags: json, karate

Is there a way to match the response data from API which contain multi-level nested array for a key where key-value pair are in different order inside the nested array in karate?

Scenario: Verify original data contains expected data

```
def original = {"a":[{"a1":"1","a2":"2","a3":["r3"]},{"a1":"11","a2":"21","a3":["r1","r2","r3"]}],"b":"abc","c":{"c1":"test","c3":"test2"}}
string level2 = ["<r1>","<r3>","<r2>"]
replace.r1=r1
replace.r2=r2
replace.r3=r3
json level2 = level2 
def level1 = [{"a1":"1","a2":"2","a3":["r3"]},{"a1":"11","a2":"21","a3":'#(^^level2)'}]
def expected = {"a":'#(^^level1)',"b":"abc","c":{"c1":"test","c3":"test2"}}
```

I expect dynamic values in r1, r2, r3 supplied through karate.call()

I tried:

```
string level1 = [{"a1":"1","a2":"2","a3":["r3"]},{"a1":"11","a2":"21","a3":["<r1>","<r3>","<r2>"]}]
replace level1.r1=r1
replace level1.r2=r2
replace level1.r3=r3
json level1 = level1 
def expected = {"a":'#(^+level1)',"b":"abc","c":{"c1":"test","c3":"test2"}}
```

It failed to match. Also, s3 values should only be r1,r2,r3

Is there any way to match multi level arrays with contains only for each array level

Comment: is there any way you can simplify your scenario, I am unable to understand this. please leave out the replace stuff. what is the json match you are trying to do

Comment: @PeterThomas def original = {"a":[{"a1":"1","a2":"2","a3":["r3"]},{"a1":"11","a2":"21","a3":["r1","r2","r3"]}],"b":"abc","c":{"c1":"test","c3":"test2"}}
def level2 = ["r1","r3","r2"]
def level1 = [{"a1":"1","a2":"2","a3":["r3"]},{"a1":"11","a2":"21","a3":'#(^^level2)'}]
def expected = {"a":'#(^^level1)',"b":"abc","c":{"c1":"test","c3":"test2"}} --> this worked! So, the alternate to contains only deep can be multiple contains only at each level.

Comment: okay I don't understand this because it is too much for me to make sense of, but I suggest you add an answer yourself with the solution (and a nice explanation) so you can help others